# Satisfied condition

Tags: php, mysql

When doing a MySql PHP query using an "OR", how can I know which of the two conditions has been met?

Example:

```
if($mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE cpf = '0' OR state = '0'")->fetch_assoc()){
//Which was satisfied?

}
```

Remembering that in each of these queries will come a maximum of 2 records.

I thought about doing this:

```
if($th = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE cpf = '0' OR state = '0'")->fetch_assoc()){
    while($row = $th){
       if($row['cpf'] == "0"){
               echo "CPF";

       }else if($row['state'] == "0"){
               echo "state";

      }
   }
}
```

But is not there a "right" way to do it? No need for these ifs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to check that from the result array got from executing query.

```
if($row = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE cpf = '0' OR state = '0'")->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($row['cpf'] == 0) { /* cpf satisfied*/ }
    if ($row['state'] == 0) { /* state satisfied*/ }
}
```

A small suggestion to you: Try to use `$mysqli` than `$mysql`

You can check this also:

```
SELECT *, 
(CASE WHEN cpf = '0' THEN 'cpf satisfied' 
WHEN state = '0' THEN 'state satisfied' END) AS satisfied 
FROM `table` WHERE cpf = '0' OR state = '0'
```

Comment: Is that the only way?

Comment: I don't think we can distinguish the satisfied condition from query itself. As the earlier answer it can be done, but number of query & code lines must be higher than this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really know which of the two conditions has been met. If you want to know you will have to execute them separately like below:

```
if($mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE cpf = '0'")->fetch_assoc()){
//cpf = 0 was satisfied

}
if($mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE state = '0'")->fetch_assoc()){
//state = 0 was satisfied

}
```